# Design "Page Not Found" page for Mobile

Tags: feature-request, mobile

I often use this site on my smartphone. The mobile version works great, but when I end up to a page which is not found (like deleted question),  it redirects me to full version of site.
Can you please re-design that page to adjust on small screen?

Comment: Perhaps this should be migrated to MSO

Comment: @SachinShekhar [asked this on MSO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121647/design-page-not-found-page-for-mobile), for those that are curious.